# Redis Many Subscribe

Tags: node.js, redis

After reading many articles , I decide to user socketio + node + Redis .
I need to create node js server to handle many request

now , think I have facebook like site

every user connect to an Node JS server ( randomly ) and he will subscribe to his user id like here

`client.subscribe('<the user id of person who user this'> );`

And another user many publish a message to him easily .

`client2.publish("<user id of receiver>" , "the is a notifcation");`

Now a client from node 5 ( as example ) can receive notification of user of node 21 ( as example)

it seem that there is no problem , but wait , think we get 100 million user , so 100 million subscriber we have , if a person send notification to specific user , another subscriber should check if that is they own message ( redis do this automatically )

Do you think Redis can handle this problem , Even I have not tested this scenario  in real  world , as I have not found 100 million user yet!

As I am very new to redis , Please Redis,Node Expert help me of this scenario ...

Comment: Well, maybe you should worry about it once you get 100mln users? Do not preoptimize.

Comment: each node js can not handle more than 5000 req at mid range server , so it is not need to have 100 million user , 100 million was an example , even we may get that one day ! haha

Comment: I do not understand the question. Are you asking if Redis can handle millions of pub/sub channels?

Comment: @akonsu  :yes, and does that effect speed of redis ?